# Is it possible to plot SpatRaster over a shapefile?

Tags: spatial, shapefile

I'm trying to run an SDM within my local area (Warwickshire, UK). I have a shapefile for the county boundary and now have the predicted occurrence from the GLM as a SpatRaster. However, I can't plot the two together, although I can add the observation data points to either one. I'm still really new to r so apologies in advance!

```
##setup for warwickshire boundary.shp 
library(sf)
shp<-st_read("data/boundary.shp")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(st_geometry(shp),axes=TRUE,col="grey95")

##only plotting areas where probability of occurrence is greater than threshold
plot(glm_predict>glm_threshold,
axes=TRUE,
col=c(NA,"olivedrab"))

#add observations
points(x=obs_data$x,
y=obs_data$y,
col="black",
pch="+",
cex=0.75)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the implementation and properties of statistical distributions (description of `distribution` tag)?